# If 3 out of 5 randomly chosen reports used incorrect style, how many to expect out of 125

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

> A teacher randomly reads 5 written reports from the 125 she has to grade. He finds that 3 reports did not follow the correct style. At this time same rate, how many of the 125 can she expect to not follow the correct style?

How do you do this question? You don't have to give the answer, just how you solve.

Answer (score 1):

The problem tells you that 3 out of 5 of the papers the teacher looks at "did not follow the correct style".  Then the "rate" of papers not following the style is $3/5$.  To find the answer, you need to figure out how many out of 125 makes 3/5.  That is, find $X$ such that $X/125 = 3/5$.

Comment: Thxs that helped!!